# How do I link fields of a 'user content type' to the actual logged in user?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I'm using the [User Content Type](https://drupal.org/project/user_content_type) module (Drupal 7) in order to store some fields for each user, such as "zip code."

Now, in this node_edit page, I made a variant for a Catalog node, for a specific role. (Let's say "salesman".)

How do I link the actual logged in user with their respective *User* node, to show and store the "zip code" field in the Catalog node?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the module? A better way to associate fields with a specific user is via Admin => Configuration => People => Account settings => Manage fields

Comment: @Craig Hyatt, many thanks for your answer, I think it's the right solution. Obviously I didn't see this via in my admin menu: https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu; best regards!

Comment: Glad to help. I added my comment as an answer below for future reference. Please consider marking it the accepted solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 7, the simplest way to associate fields with a specific user is via Admin => Configuration => People => Account settings => Manage fields.

Because of its simplicity, I recommend this approach as a starting point. If it's not flexible enough, consider the contributed [Profile 2 module](https://drupal.org/project/profile2).